# Flutter column not center in vertical

Tags: flutter

I need to center my column vertically i try with   mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment but dont know why its not coming in center. Here is my code

```
return Container(
      height: stackHeight * 0.4,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff404040),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: Radius.circular(15.0))
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(

            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right:10,
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10 ,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  maxLength: 56,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    counterText: '',
                      labelText: 'Would Question',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue
                      ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                ),
                TextField(
                  maxLength: 56,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    counterText: '',
                      labelText: 'Rather Question',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red
                      ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                ),

                RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                  _submitData();

                }, child: Text('Add Question', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white
                ),),color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]
Also, don't know on border-radius its showing white corners as you see in image emulator I need to remove this white also.

also, When i am opening the keyboard its cover the whole bottomsheet nothing is showing also the yellow line error showing is it possible when keyboard open the bottom shettup move on up side

Comment: Wrapping the column widget with a center widget doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan no i try its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` widget with `Center` widget. And for white corner you can wrap your main container with other `container` and set `color: new Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 0.5),`

Working Code here

```
   return Container(
      color: new Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 0.5),
      child: Container(
        height: stackHeight * 0.4,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xff404040),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: Radius.circular(15.0))
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(

                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right:10,
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10 ,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        maxLength: 56,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          counterText: '',
                          labelText: 'Would Question',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        maxLength: 56,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          counterText: '',
                          labelText: 'Rather Question',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.red
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                      ),

                      RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                        _submitData();

                      }, child: Text('Add Question', style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white
                      ),),color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give a transparent background so it will remove the white corners. `Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`
Also can wrap center with Singlescroll widget. As mention in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

instead of this

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
return Container(
      height: stackHeight * 0.4,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff404040),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: Radius.circular(15.0))
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(

            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right:10,
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10 ,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  maxLength: 56,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    counterText: '',
                      labelText: 'Would Question',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue
                      ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                ),
                TextField(
                  maxLength: 56,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    counterText: '',
                      labelText: 'Rather Question',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red
                      ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                ),

                RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                  _submitData();

                }, child: Text('Add Question', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white
                ),),color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem you need to `crossAxisAlignment ` add in your second `Column`

Comment: I think i forget to mention need to center the inputs not t he button :D Sorry my mistake after wrap SingleScrollView with center then its working